# Cannot insert a default entry in Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('player', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('victories')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();

    });

    for($i = 0 ; $i < 6 ; $i++){
        DB::table('player')->insert([]);
    }
}
```

I want to insert 5 players, but Eloquent won't let me. It says that the insert function needs a parameter. This function works fine with other migrations where I actually need to input something in the array, but it won't work if it is empty.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for($i = 0 ; $i < 6 ; $i++) {
    DB::table('player')->insert(['id' => DB::raw('null')]);
}
```